# How to output registration form data to the current page and another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

As the tittle says, how do I output a registration form data to the current page(form.php) and another page(profile.php) if the submitted form data has been successful and validated? I've been trying to search how to do this but couldn't find anything useful. I tried changing the action to profile.php where I want the user's data to be displayed, but when I did that, I couldn't display the errors in my form page.

Basically, I want the errors to be displayed in the form if the user's input is incorrect and once he filled out everything correctly and submitted the form, I want the data to be displayed to his profile (profile.php). Like if I do `<?php echo $_POST['username']?>` in profile.php, I want his username to be displayed in profile.php. Is there a way to do this? I'm still kind of new to this...

Is there anything I should add or change? I'm not sure how I can output the data to profile.php

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
    require 'core.inc.php';
    require 'connect.inc.php';

    if(count($_POST) > 0){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $password_hash = md5($password);
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];

        $validated = true;

        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$username)){
            $usernameErr = " Only letters and white space allowed";
            $validated = false;
        } else if(empty($username)){
            $usernameErr = ' Enter your username';
            $validated = false;
        }

        if(strlen($username)>30){
            $error = 'Please ahear to maxlength of fields.';
        }

        if(empty($password)){
            $passErr = ' Enter your password';
            $validated = false;
        }

        if (!empty($email) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = " Invalid email";
            $validated = false;
        } else if(empty($email)){
            $emailErr = ' Enter your email';
            $validated = false;
        }

        if(empty($gender)){
            $genderErr = ' Select your gender';
            $validated = false;
        }

        if(empty($age)){
            $ageErr = ' Select your age';
            $validated = false;
        }

        if($validated === true){
            $query = "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'";
                $query_run = mysql_query($query);

                if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)==1){
                    $error = 'The username already exists.';
                } else {
                    $query = "INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('','".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($password_hash)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."')";
                    if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
                        header('Location: register_success.php');
                    } else {
                        $error = 'Sorry, we couldn\'t register you at this time. Try again later.';
                    }
                }   
        }
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
form{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 470px;
    margin-top:150px;
}
label{
     width: 75px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.error{
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $error?></span>
    <br><br>
    <form action="register.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
        <h2>Register</h2>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="50" value="<?php if(isset($username)){echo $username;}?>">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $usernameErr?></span>
            <br><br>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $passErr?></span>
            <br><br>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="30" value="<?php if(isset($email)){echo $email;}?>">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr?></span>
            <br><br>
        <label>Gender</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female">Female
            <span class="error"><?php echo $genderErr?></span>
            <br><br>
        <label>Age</label>
            <select name="age" class="age">
                <option value> </option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
            </select>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $ageErr?></span>
            <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question. You have a script, register_success.php. If you want to display the information on profile.php after successful registration, just change the location to profile.php instead of register_success.php.  Then if there is an error, it will continue to load the form.php and if there isn't, it will go to profile.php. No?

Answer (score 0):

*Data Persistence*

HTTP is a stateless protocol so it will not remember information across different requests.
In order to display the login information, you will need to persist this information.
The INSERT INTO statement that you have does that already so all you need to do on your profile page is to retrieve the information from your database and display it using a SELECT SQL statement.

*Authentication*

You will also need to know which user record to retrive from your database.
This is usually done by asking your user for credentials (e.g. his email address and his password).
Based on this, you can verify that there is a user with these credentials and then retrieve the appropriate data.
You may want to try a PHP login system tutorial such as this one: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html.

*Edit*:
You should also make sure you keep your form in sync with your SQL INSERT statement.
You have username, email, password, gender and age in your form but only username, email and password in your INSERT statement so gender and age will not be added to your database and the data will not be remembered.