# Sending Form Data Using POST To The Current Page And Another PHP Page At The Same Time

Tags: php, forms

I have seen another person ask this question in stack overflow but I did not get any clear answer/idea from ['his post'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477166/how-to-output-registration-form-data-to-the-current-page-and-another-page). I want to know whether there is a way of sending form data via POST to the current PHP page `addstudio.php` to verify the entered data & if the entered data is valid it gets redirected to the next PHP page `getstudio.php`.

To send the form data to the current page I used the following line:-

```
<form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "post">
```

This is just done to validate the form information and if the form is left blank then a message is displayed in the same PHP page, the code for this is shown below.

```
<?php
 $valid = true;
 $studioIdError = $studioNameError = $studioAddressError = $studioPCodeError = $studioTelNoError = "";
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
     if(empty($_POST["studioId"])){
         $studioIdError = " *This Field Cannot Be Empty";
         $valid = false;
     }
     if(empty($_POST["studioName"])){
         $studioNameError = " *This Field Cannot Be Empty";
         $valid = false;
     }
     if(empty($_POST["studioAddress"])){
         $studioAddressError = " *This Field Cannot Be Empty";
         $valid = false;
     }
     if(empty($_POST["studioPCode"])){
         $studioPCodeError = " *This Field Cannot Be Empty";
         $valid = false;
     }
     if(empty($_POST["studioTelNo"])){
         $studioTelNoError = " *This Field Cannot Be Empty";
         $valid = false;
     }
 }
?>
```

To the above code I want to know if there is a way I can get the `getstudio.php` page to run when `$valid = true`.

I cannot use the code `include 'getstudio.php';` because I want `getstudio.php` to run on a seperate page.

I cannot use the code `header("Location:getstudio.php");exit();` to run either because the values in the global array `$_POST[]` is not sent to the PHP page like it is when the page is called directly from the form (Eg:- `<form action = 'getstudio.php' method = 'post'>`).

Is there a way of running the `getstudio.php` page while sending the values stored in the `$_POST[]` array to the `getstudio.php` page when `$valid = true`?

Comment: If you wanna send the same `POST` data to two different URLs, the best way is to use AJAX. Check the results [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=post+to+two+different+forms).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't know anything about AJAX as I am still new to this. I will research more and find out how it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your current page

```
<?php
 $_POST["studioName"] = 'testdata';
 $valid = true;

 if(empty($_POST["studioName"])){
   $studioNameError = " *This Field Cannot Be Empty";
   $valid = false;
 }

// send data to getstudio.php if valid 
if($valid){  ?>
    <form method="post" action="getstudio.php" id="senddata">
      <input type="hidden" name="postdata" value="<?php print_r($_POST); ?>">  
    </form> 
<script>
    document.getElementById("senddata").submit();
</script>
<?php  } ?>
```

Here is your getstudio.php file to receive validated post data

```
<?php
  echo '<pre>';

  print_r($_POST['postdata']);

  die;
```

Comment: The code you have provided works, keeping another hidden form and entering the values of the original to the hidden form and then passing the hidden form with `action = "getstudio.php"`.

Comment: I just passed an array of all post data  in hidden field using form submit. You can also use SESSION for sending data to another page :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options.

1. Use AJAX to validate the form; then, if valid, do the submit.
2. Store the data somewhere client-side or server-side between pages (cookies or sessions).
3. Send a specially-crafted html that makes the browser to mimic a user sending a form. [ugly, the user sees a redraw]
4. Keep both validation and processing in the same page (why separate?).

In any case don't forget to re-validate before acting upon user data, unless absolutely sure the data can't be affected by a user (in the list above, only when storing data in a session, and still not recommended). Then, if validating again anyways, why bother with a separate page?

Comment: 1. Yes I tried with AJAX but unfortunately I failed as I did not understand the code very well and could not properly implement it to my code (my fault). 2. Storing the data separately in a session I can do but it could add complications later on (worth a shot). 3. Send a specially-crafted html form, as you said is ugly (I completely agree) but I tried it and it worked. 4. why bother with a separate page? Cause it is in the requirements that I have gotten, that's why.

Answer (score 1):

So as i understand you want to send Data first Addstudio.php than Getstudio.php but you want second one with redirection.

Make your HTML like this :

```
<form action="getstudio.php" method="POST">
    <!-- etc -->
</form>
```

Make your Javascript like this (include jQuery):

```
$(".your-form-class").on('submit',function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var instance = $(this);
    var formData = new FormData($(".your-form-class")[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:formData,
        url:"addstudio.php",
        success:function(response){
            instance.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried the above code as you said but the form just seems to completely ignore the data validation processes in `addstudio.php` and goes to `getstudio.php`. I added the javascript code that you showed above along with the JQuery CDN.